# LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL to a specific View

Tags: python, django

Is there a way to specify a view in the LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL setting in settings.py? I am using django-allauth for registration and logging in.

What i am trying to do is as follows:

When the user is logged in, determine if the user is_user_A or is_user_B (is_user_A being default).

If is_user_A -> redirect to is_user_A-dashboard.html

If is_user_B -> redirect to is_user_B-dashboard.html

My code is as follows:

views.py

```
def logged_in(request):
   if request.user.is_user_A:
      return render(request, "is_user_A-dashboard.html")
   if request.user.is_user_B:
      return render(request, "is_user_B-dashboard.html")
```

settings.py

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
```

Comment: Does it work or something?
It gives an error or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add a url in your `urls.py`

```
url(r'^home$',logged_in , name ="logged_in"),
```

and put this `url` in `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL`

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/home'
```

Comment: Use `reverse_lazy` instead of hardcoding the url (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse-lazy)